# Comment s'explique cette mention de la "harpe à Sieyès" ?

Tags: histoire, argot

Bonjour,

Dans *Féerie pour une autre fois I* :

> la broderie du Temps est musique... Sourde peut-être... preste, et
> puis plus rien... petit coucou, horloge qui bat, votre cœur, la vague
> au bord, le môme qui pleure, **l'harpe à Sieyès**...

Comment s'explique cette allusion à Sieyès, homme politique ? Faut-il comprendre le mot *[harpe](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/1724)* dans le sens argotique de *barreaux d'une grille de prison* ?

Answer (score 1):

Ma réponse n'en est pas vraiment une, comme ce que je propose est une conjecture, assez plausible mais à sonder plus sérieusement. Plus de quelques lignes s'imposent pour la présenter, ce qui est la raison pour ne pas en faire un commentaire.

(*crochets et caractères gras de user LPH*)

On constate qu'un certain Suisse nommé *La Harpe* (1754-1838) est un contemporain de Sieyès (1748-1836) ; ce dernier est un homme politique, initialement homme d'église, et le premier est aussi un homme politique, à la  manière d'un activiste, un homme de loi initialement.

> ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric-C%C3%A9sar_de_La_Harpe)) Frédéric-César de La Harpe obtient un doctorat en droit à Tübingen en 1774. Il exerce comme avocat dans le pays de Vaud, mais s'y ennuie vite et tolère mal la domination bernoise. En 1782, il saisit l'occasion de partir en acceptant le poste de précepteur de deux jeunes Russes voyageant en Italie et à l'occasion de ce grand tour il est aussi passé par Naples, ville où il avait été initié dans la franc-maçonnerie dans la Loge "La Vittoria" en 1762. En 1784, l'impératrice Catherine charge ce républicain de l'éducation de ses petits-fils Alexandre et Constantin. La Harpe ne se présente pas comme un simple professeur, mais comme un « guide des princes », chargé d'en faire des hommes éclairés. Pendant onze ans, il enseignera à Alexandre les principes libéraux, le sens de la justice, son rôle pour le bonheur de ses peuples.

> ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmanuel-Joseph_Siey%C3%A8s)) Sieyès devient célèbre dès 1788 par son Essai sur les privilèges. Mais c'est plus encore sa brochure de 1789 *Qu'est-ce que le Tiers-État* ?, texte fondateur de la Révolution française, qui obtient un grand retentissement et assure sa popularité. Il prend ainsi une part active à la Révolution française jusqu'à sa fin, par sa participation au coup d'État du 18 Brumaire [9 novembre 1799].

La connection qui pourrait très bien exister prend une certaine réalité dans la corroboration qui existe entre la préposition « à » comprise comme signifiant « s'adressant à », et la révèlation du fait qu'il a pu exister une certaine correspondance écrite entre La Harpe et Sieyès, celle-ci rendu très apparente dans le passage suivant.

> ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric-C%C3%A9sar_de_La_Harpe)) La Révolution française de 1789 l'enthousiasme [lui, La Harpe]. En 1793, il publie dans un journal anglais des lettres dénonçant le despotisme bernois et envoie au pays une pétition réclamant les droits politiques pour les Vaudois. En 1795, La Harpe quitte la cour de Russie et s'installe à Genthod, le retour à Rolle lui étant refusé par Berne. De cet asile, La Harpe continue son action politique, **multipliant** les brochures, les projets de réforme et **les contacts avec Paris**. Avec Peter Ochs, de Bâle, **La Harpe sollicite l'intervention diplomatique de la France** et l'agression armée de la fin de l'année 1797 les laissera pantois.
> La Harpe ne participera pas au gouvernement helvétique imposé par la France, il restera à Paris comme négociateur au profit des Vaudois. Il entrera dans le Directoire en 1798, mais l'expérience du gouvernement sera un échec cinglant. Il quitte la Suisse en 1800, passe quelques mois en Russie; il s'établit ensuite en France et y vivra retiré de toute vie publique jusqu'à la chute de Napoléon Ier.

> ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoire_de_la_Suisse_sous_domination_fran%C3%A7aise)) À la suite de l'échec d'un soulèvement dans le canton de Vaud contre Berne, les meneurs se réfugient à Paris où ils poussent à la fin 1797 le gouvernement français à envahir la Suisse, qui capitule une année plus tard. Le gouvernement français met alors en place le nouveau régime de la République helvétique, État centralisé et unitaire dont les limites administratives internes sont largement redessinées.

Considérant l'énorme propension de Céline à se laisser aller aux images populaires, il n'y qu'un pas pour comprendre dans les termes « le môme qui pleure » comment Céline considèrerait le rapport entre La Harpe et Sieyès.

Il existe certaines [lettres de La Harpe à Sieyès](https://journals.openedition.org/ahrf/298?lang=en#tocto1n4).

> Comme l’exprime le Directeur Frédéric-César Laharpe (1754-1838) dans une motion du 4 novembre 1799 : « Le séjour de deux armées sur notre territoire a réduit notre république à la dernière extrémité. Notre existence comme nation, notre liberté, notre indépendance, nos vies et nos fortunes sont réduites à attendre humblement au vainqueur de prononcer sur nos destinées ». Dans sa lettre à Sieyès, du 6 juin 1799, le patriote vaudois espère que « Le gouvernement français n’a jamais voulu sans doute que notre révolution fût acquise aux dépens de notre existence » 6. Et d’ajouter le 5 juillet, dans une autre lettre à Sieyès : « Notre détresse est extrême, et si elle se prolonge l’Helvétie est ruinée. »

> De l’aveu même du Directoire helvétique, la plus grande incertitude planait sur ses relations avec la France, le Directoire helvétique réfractaire risquant de se faire « cisalpiniser » par le général Masséna aux dires de La Harpe, qui déplorait « la politique bornée du Directoire » français.

Néanmoins, bien plus de recherche reste nécessaire, en particulier une examen complet de toutes les lettres, et plus encore, une étude qui révèlerait jusqu'à quel point Céline aurait été familier avec la tranche d'histoire qui est en  rapport avec la  conjecture que je suspecte.

Comment: Merci beaucoup, LPH !